# Issue when populating managed schema for our Sitecore Solr index

Tags: solr, indexing, multisite

I'm am getting an issue when trying to rebuild the Sitecore Solr index by clicking on `populate managed schema` and `rebuild`.

```
sitecore_core_index is already locked. The most likely cause is another Solr server
```

Our Solr is deployed on Azure app service. We are using the same Solr endpoints/URLs for multisite.

```
Job started: Index_Update_Collection=sitecore_core_index|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="error">
  <lst name="metadata">
    <str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.core.SolrCoreInitializationException</str>
    <str name="root-error-class">org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException</str>
  </lst>
  <str name="msg">SolrCore 'sitecore_core_index' is not available due to init failure: Index dir 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\server\solr\sitecore_core_index\data\index/' of core 'sitecore_core_index' is already locked. The most likely cause is another Solr server (or another solr core in this server) also configured to use this directory; other possible causes may be specific to lockType: native</str>
  <str name="trace">org.apache.solr.core.SolrCoreInitializationException: SolrCore 'sitecore_core_index' is not available due to init failure: Index dir 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\server\solr\sitecore_core_index\data\index/' of core 'sitecore_core_index' is already locked. The most likely cause is another Solr server (or another solr core in this server) also configured to use this directory; other possible causes may be specific to lockType: native
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:1781)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.init(HttpSolrCall.java:253)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:538)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:419)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Index dir
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try and set `WEBSITE_DISABLE_OVERLAPPED_RECYCLING=1`

**Overlapped recycling makes it so that before the current instance on an app is shut down, a new instance starts. It can in some cases cause file locking issues, in which case you can try turning it off:**

For reference - https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#disable-overlapped-recycling

Also see this issue on github - https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr/issues/347